# MySQL using SELECT in WHERE statement - best way?

Tags: mysql, select, join

I am relatively new to mysql so I am hoping you can point me in the right direction. I have two tables, 'products' is information about the items we have for sale, and 'offers' table is pricing and vendor information from various vendors we have selling that product. Both tables have 'sku' column that are related. There can be multiple vendors in the 'offers' table selling the same sku.

When I query the products table for various things, I only want results that have a vendor selling it from the 'offers' table. Right now I am using a query like:

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE
products.sku IN (SELECT offers.sku FROM offers)
AND
products.name = 'Iphone'
AND
blah.....
```

This can take longer than I want on queries that have many results. Is there a more efficient way to query these two tables? Perhaps with a JOIN? Thank you.

Comment: Converting it to a JOIN syntax will likely have the same performance as the optimizer is usually pretty smart.  What are the datatypes and indexes on your predicates?  `products.sku`, `products.name`, etc.

Comment: products.sku is a the primary key so it has it's own index, and offers.sku has it's own index as well. Data types on both are CHAR(12) since all of our skus are exactly 12 characters long.

Comment: Can you omit the `sku` predicate from your query to verify that it is in fact the cause of your performance issue?

Comment: Omitting the products.sku IN (SELECT offers.sku FROM offers) part of the query in the test query takes me from about .5sec to .3sec.

Comment: `SELECT products.* FROM products JOIN offers ON offers.sku = products.sku WHERE products.name = 'Iphone'` is the JOIN syntax, I don't think it will help your performance issue though, but may be worth while to test.

Comment: Can you give some information about your tables, such as number of records, indexes on the rest of your predicates, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`EXISTS` or a `JOIN` can be more performant than`IN`, but it's not a guarantee that your optimizer won't treat the following the same as your query.

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1
               FROM offers 
               WHERE products.sku = offers.sku)
AND     products.name = 'Iphone'
AND    blah.....
```

Indexing `sku` and other fields used in filtering criteria might be the big gain in performance you're looking for.

Comment: @TimM Are you comparing the performance of the `EXISTS` version against a cached result?  It may be that your bottleneck is the other filtering criteria, but `EXISTS` should perform same or better than `IN`.

Comment: I have query caching turned off, so I am assuming that nothing is being cached anywhere. But using the exists made the query go from about .5sec to around 2sec.

Comment: That's curious, I'd expect `EXISTS` and `JOIN` to perform identically, both same or better than `IN`, pretty well documented expectation, but who knows.  I would suggest that on a single short running query that you create a host of test queries, to check averages, since a single query can vary based on other things in the environment.

Comment: Thank you very much, yes I will do some more testing and double check indexes too. I was just hoping that there was silver bullet to kick the speed up considerably.